# UISearchControl delegate fired but no objects showing up in Tableview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uisearchcontroller

I've implemented UISearchControl (iOS8 version which is slightly different then previous ones). It seems to be firing correctly when I type stuff in according to the NSLog statement seen below, only issue is it the UITableView actually never gets updated, and I added a NSLog to the  } else { part of the numberOfRowsInSection to confirm that it's not called like so:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (tableView == self.tableView) {

        return self.objects.count;

    } else {
        // NOT BEING FIRED WHEN STUFF IS TYPED IN SEARCH BAR?
        NSLog(@"Search Results  Returned in TableView");
        return self.searchResults.count;

    }
}
```

Although these methods are firing fine...and updating the searchResults array correctly according to the NSLog added in the updateFilter method:

```
#pragma mark - UISearchResultsUpdating
-(void)updateSearchResultsForSearchController:(UISearchController *)searchController {
    NSString *searchString = [self.searchController.searchBar text];
    [self updateFilteredContentForSaleName:searchString];

    // ASSUMING THIS IS WHAT CAUSES TABLEVIEW TO REFRESH, BUT ISNT REFRESHING IT WITH NEW ARRAY?

     [((UITableViewController *)self.searchController.searchResultsController).tableView reloadData];
}
#pragma mark - Content Filtering
- (void)updateFilteredContentForSaleName:(NSString *)saleName {
    [self.searchResults removeAllObjects];

    for (PFObject *sale in self.objects)
    {
        NSString *saleTitle = [sale objectForKey:@"name"];
        if ([[saleTitle lowercaseString] hasPrefix:[saleName lowercaseString]])
        {
            [self.searchResults addObject:sale];
        }
    }
    // THIS LOG SHOWS SEARCH RESULTS CORRECTLY HOW THEY SHOULD BE, JUST NO UPDATE TO UITABLEVIEW

    NSLog(@"%@", self.searchResults);
}
```

But simply no update to the tableview...

Any idea why this is? Am I calling the refresh wrong here?:

```
 [((UITableViewController *)self.searchController.searchResultsController).tableView reloadData];
```

I've tried PFQueryTableViewController * too since that's essentially what I'm using for actual view controller, but no luck.

**EDIT**

Here is the code used to create the UISearchControl

```
@interface LocalSalesViewController () <UISearchResultsUpdating>


@property (nonatomic, strong) UISearchController *searchController;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *searchResults; // Filtered search results

@end

@implementation LocalSalesViewController
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aCoder {
    self = [super initWithCoder:aCoder];
    if (self) {
        self.parseClassName = @"Sales";
        self.pullToRefreshEnabled = YES;
        self.paginationEnabled = YES;
        self.objectsPerPage = 25;
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.searchResults = [NSMutableArray array];
    self.searchController = [[UISearchController alloc] initWithSearchResultsController:nil];
    self.searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self;
    self.searchController.searchBar.frame = CGRectMake(self.searchController.searchBar.frame.origin.x, self.searchController.searchBar.frame.origin.y, self.searchController.searchBar.frame.size.width, 44.0);
    self.tableView.tableHeaderView = self.searchController.searchBar;
    self.definesPresentationContext = YES;

}
```

Comment: what about the datasource? have you added it to the tableview and implemented its methods?

Comment: Yeah but the issue is the numberOfRowsInSection is not being called when I'm calling the refresh. The data is displaying fine normally, and would assume it'd display fine once I get the table to actually refresh.

Comment: Is it not being called or (tableView == self.tableView) ? cause if youre using the same table for displaying the search results looks like you'd allways fall into the if condition

Comment: Oh so you're saying the IF is going to always be called the way I have it set up due to me using them in the same tableView? How would I go about fixing this to work with the same tableView then? Or would I have to make two seperate ones, and somehow hide the other and display one over?

Comment: Post your code where you actually create and setup the search controller. You should also look at the "Table Search with UISearchController" sample app.

Comment: Done sorry about that, I will take a look as well and post any updates if I'm able to resolve it thanks. Think it has to do with me using the same tableView for both results so only if and not else is being called in the numberOfRowsForSection.. would make sense to me but no idea how to fix that.

Comment: You can't pass `nil` to `initWithSearchResultsController:` and expect anything to work. You need to pass in a view controller that will be used to show the results.

Comment: nil is referring to the self tableview, I read somewhere you couldn't pass self because when I tried I got an error instead to use nil for the current views tableview? I could of read that wrong but it fixed that error when I did that. I went ahead and just allocated and initalized a new UITableViewController instead of nil and it works great now thanks! Feel free to post that as the answer and I'll accept

Comment: My bad. You are right. Passing `nil` does use searched view controller.

Comment: put a breakpoint to check what I said. In your case the condition would be if(_searchbox.textfield isempty){} else{}

Comment: Ok cool thanks, wonder why I couldn't just use that one then oh well, the alternative works fine. I was wondering in order to get the searchBar to stick if I would have to create a custom ViewController with UITableView for that or if there's a way to add it above the UITableViewController rather then in the header programmatically?